# What is the number of digits of this number: $2^{333111160}$?

Tags: prime-numbers

My **question** is: What is the number of digits of this number? : $$2^{333111160}$$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177973/is-there-a-way-to-determine-how-many-digits-a-power-of-2-will-contain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
333111160 = \log_2 2^{333111160} = \frac{\log_{10}333111160}{\log_{10}2}
$$
$$
\text{So }\log_{10} 333111160 = 333111160\log_{10}2 \approx 100276451.05\ldots
$$
This is between $100276451$ and $100276452$, so the number has $100276452$ digits.

But this answer is only as good as the calculator I used.

Comment: @alex.jordan : Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

$$2^{333111160} \sim 10^{(\log_{10} 2) 333111160} \sim 100266459\text{ digits}$$

Comment: Why did you set part of your answer in MathJax but not all of it?  (I changed it.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks. I noticed that with a more accurate value of $\log_{10}2$, you get 100276451 digits and I was editing that in.

Comment: @alex.jordan Was that comment for me?

Comment: In at least one expression, you had only three $1$s.  I changed it.