# Value of the logarithmic expression

Tags: logarithms

Why $\log_6 \sqrt{6} = 1/2$?
I know that $\sqrt{6} = 6^{1/2}$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are logarithms?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722125/what-are-logarithms)

Comment: Why is everyone behind the origin of logarithm and not how to use?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sqrt{6} = 6^{1/2}$ we have:
$$\log_6 \sqrt{6} = \log_6 6^{1/2} = 1/2$$

You can think of $\log_6 n$ as "*the exponent I need to apply to $6$ in order to obtain $n$*". Well, since in this particular case $n=6^{1/2}$ it follows naturally that the exponent you need to apply is in fact $1/2$.

You can also evaluate the expression using these properties of logarithms:
$$\begin{align*}
\log_a b^c &= c \log_a b\\
\log_a a &= 1
\end{align*}$$

You can check that: $\log_6 6^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2} \log_6 6 = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @user161304: Remember to accept the answer if it was helpful to you. Otherwise, don't hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: So basically both of the 6's cancel out and leave you with 1/2

Comment: Well it's not very correct to say that they "cancel out", because actually they don't. You can think of $y = \log_6 6$ as $6^y = 6$. So what's the value of $y$, i.e. of the log? It can only be $1$.

Answer (score 1):

So what is a logarithm?

It is essentially the exponent value required, with a particular base, to give the value.  In the equation below it is easy to see that x must 2.  6 is the base and x is the exponent.

$${6^x} = 36$$

The logarithm is the formal definition of this relationship.

$${Log_6(6^{1\over2})} = {x}$$

Let's rewrite that in the same style as the first:

$${6^x}={6^{1\over2}}$$

So obviously x must be $1\over2$.  But if you notice the 6 is common to both sides and you really only care about the exponents, and that's where the log comes in.